# what is possibility of collision in djb2 function?

Tags: javascript, hash, cryptography, hashcode

I am trying to generate unique id using djb2 hash function for string like

`"114.143.227.82Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0"`

What is the possibility of collision using this algorithm which is given below in javascript.

`String.prototype.hashCode = function(){
    var hash = 5381;
    if (this.length === 0) return hash;
    for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
        var character  = this.charCodeAt(i);
        hash  = (( hash << 5 ) + hash ) ^ character; 
    }
    return hash;
}`

**Usage:**

`var hash = new String("114.143.227.82"+navigator.userAgent).hashCode();`

`alert(hash);`

**Reference:**

http://www.cse.yorku.ca/~oz/hash.html

For the above string I am getting -ve integer value. How to return +ve integer for those types of string?

Comment: This has little to nothing to do with crypto. What's a -ve integer? What is the range of possible input values? This seems like a hash as used in collections, usually they are stored together in a list when such an element evaluates to the same hash value; are you interested in correctness or efficiency?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution after modifying the above code.

`String.prototype.hashCode = function(){
    var hash = 5381;
    if (this.length === 0) return hash;
    for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
        var character  = this.charCodeAt(i);

        hash = hash * 33 ^character;
    }
    return hash >>>0;
}`